# Table Note in Long Table

Tags: longtable, tablenotes

I am generating a long table. I want to put the table note right after the caption. For this purpose, I placed the table note in the caption. Howeer, caption and table note appear in the same line. If i put `\\` after the caption both caption and table notes are left aligned. However, only table note should be left aligned and caption should remain centrally aligned. Moreover, I also want to make the line after the p-value disappear in the last row of the table. The MWE is given below:

```
     \documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
     \usepackage[para]{threeparttable}
     \usepackage{booktabs,longtable,tabularx}
     \usepackage{caption}
     \setlength{\LTcapwidth}{7in}
     \usepackage{ltablex}
     \usepackage{siunitx}
     \usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttablex}
     \begin{document}

     \begin{longtable}{l*{4}{S}} \caption[Ordinary Least Square Estimations]         {Ordinary Least Square Estimations\vspace{1ex} \\
             Note: This table provides the results of OLS. Four models are estimated here. Models details are provided in the main body of the document. 
     }
             \label{tab:te3}\\
             \toprule
             {\bfseries{}}  &{\bfseries(1)} & {\bfseries(2)} &{\bfseries(3)} & {\bfseries(4)} \\%
             \endfirsthead
             \caption{-- continued from previous page}\\
             \toprule
             & {\bfseries(1)} & {\bfseries(2)} &{\bfseries(3)} & {\bfseries(4)}\\
             \midrule
             \endhead
             \bottomrule
             \addlinespace
             \multicolumn{5}{r}{\footnotesize Continued on next page} \\
             \endfoot
             \bottomrule
             \addlinespace
             \insertTableNotes\\
             \endlastfoot %
             \midrule
             A   & 0.022*** & 0.019*** & 0.021*** & 0.020*** \\
             B    & -0.002 & -0.008** & -0.010*** & -0.010** \\
             C  & 0.024 & -0.007 & -0.004 & -0.015 \\
            D    & -0.217*** & -0.314*** & -0.275*** & -0.262*** \\
             E   & -0.133 & -0.068 & -0.071 & -0.026 \\
             F   & 0.023 & 0.003 & 0.022 & 0.019 \\
             G    & -0.003*** & -0.003*** & -0.002** & -0.002** \\
             H    & -0.015 & -0.021** & -0.041*** & -0.045*** \\
             I   & -0.005** & -0.006*** & -0.006*** & -0.007*** \\
             J   & 0.184 & 0.346*** & 0.129 & 0.051 \\
             K & -0.006* & -0.007** & -0.007** & -0.009*** \\
             L & -0.014 & -0.022* & -0.021* & -0.023** \\
             M  & -0.006 & -0.001 & -0.004 & -0.002 \\
             N    & 0.001 & 0.004 & 0.009 & 0.003 \\
             O  & 0.01  & 0.017 & -0.003 & 0.003 \\
             P  & -0.077 & -0.146*** & -0.103** & -0.093** \\
             Q  & -0.022*** & -0.002 & -0.004 & -0.007 \\
             R   & 0.028*** & 0.035*** & 0.032*** & 0.027*** \\
             S    & 0.006 & 0.035*** & 0.026*** & 0.025*** \\
             T   & 0.0003 & -0.007 & 0.005 & -0.009 \\
             U   & -0.149** & -0.052 & 0.055 & 0.077 \\
             V   & -0.017* & -0.020** & -0.016* & -0.014* \\
             W     & -0.006 & -0.005 & 0.002 & -0.0004 \\
             Z    & -0.006 & -0.003 & -0.003 & -0.006 \\
             AB  & 0.004*** & 0.005*** & 0.005*** & 0.004*** \\
             AC  & -0.056** & -0.058** & -0.045* & -0.028 \\
             AD   & 1.985** & 0.856 & 0.178 & 0.306 \\
             AE    &       & -0.028*** & -0.012* & -0.012 \\
             AF   &       & 0.043*** & 0.044*** & 0.042*** \\
             AG    &       & -0.043*** & -0.037*** & -0.036*** \\
             AH   &       & -0.007 & -0.004 & -0.008 \\
             AI    &       & -0.003 & -0.004 & -0.003 \\
             AJ    &       & -0.014 & -0.003 & 0.004 \\
             BA  &       &       & -0.030*** & -0.031*** \\
             BC  &       &       & -0.038*** & -0.039*** \\
             BD  &       &       & -0.042*** & -0.044*** \\
             BE  &       &       & -0.025*** & -0.028*** \\
             BF  &       &       & -0.032*** & -0.036*** \\
             BH  &       &       & -0.034*** & -0.058*** \\
             BJ  &       &       & 0.006 & -0.013 \\
             BI  &       &       & -0.027*** & -0.048*** \\
             BL  &       &       & -0.028*** & -0.051*** \\
             BM  &       &       & 0.030*** & 0.012 \\
             BL * FC &       &       &       & -0.0005 \\
             BM * FC &       &       &       & 0.009** \\
             BC * FC &       &       &       & 0.013 \\
             BO * FC &       &       &       & 0.052*** \\
             BP * FC &       &       &       & -0.036** \\
             Constant & 0.131* & 0.039 & -0.032 & -0.03 \\
             \midrule
             Observations & 1,210 & 1,210 & 1,210 & 1,210 \\
             $R^2$    & 0.126 & 0.187 & 0.28  & 0.301 \\
             Adjusted $R^2$ & 0.106 & 0.164 & 0.254 & 0.272 \\
             Residual Std. Error & 0.003 & 0.003 & 0.002 & 0.002 \\
             $F$ Statistic & 6.325*** & 8.204*** & 10.552***  & 0.417*** \\
             \bottomrule
             \multicolumn{5}{c}{*p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01} \\
             \end{longtable}%

             \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the table to fit within the margins, use`ltablex` and an `X` column. Additionally, fix thetableèformat of `S` columns to the exact number of digits, and `ThhreePartTablex` package for the table note:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.3pt}

 \usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}%
 \usepackage{longtable, tabularx, ltablex}
\usepackage{siunitx} %
\usepackage[flushleft, online]{threeparttablex} %

\begin{document}

\begin{ThreePartTable}
  \sisetup{table-format=-2.3, table-space-text-post=***, table-number-alignment=center}
\keepXColumns
\begin{TableNotes}\footnotesize
 \item[\hspace{-\fontdimen2\font}]\emph{Note:} This table provides the results of OLS. Four models are estimated
 here. Models details are provided in the main body of the document.
\end{TableNotes}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X@{}S[table-format =-1.4]*{2}{S}S[table-format =-1.4]}
 \caption{Ordinary Least Square Estimations}\label{tab:te3}\\
\insertTableNotes\\
\addlinespace%
%\toprule
% &{\bfseries(1)} & {\bfseries(2)} &{\bfseries(3)} & {\bfseries(4)} \\%
 \endfirsthead
 \caption[]{-- continued from previous page}\\
 \toprule
 & {\bfseries(1)} & {\bfseries(2)} &{\bfseries(3)} & {\bfseries(4)}\\
 \midrule
 \endhead
 \bottomrule
 \addlinespace
 \multicolumn{5}{r}{\footnotesize Continued on next page} \\
 \endfoot
 \bottomrule
 \addlinespace
 %\insertTableNotes\\
 \endlastfoot %
  \midrule
 A & 0.022*** & 0.019*** & 0.021*** & 0.020*** \\
 B & -0.002 & -0.008** & -0.010*** & -0.010** \\
 C & 0.024 & -0.007 & -0.004 & -0.015 \\
 D & -0.217*** & -0.314*** & -0.275*** & -0.262*** \\
 E & -0.133 & -0.068 & -0.071 & -0.026 \\
 F & 0.023 & 0.003 & 0.022 & 0.019 \\
 G & -0.003*** & -0.003*** & -0.002** & -0.002** \\
 H & -0.015 & -0.021** & -0.041*** & -0.045*** \\
 I & -0.005** & -0.006*** & -0.006*** & -0.007*** \\
 J & 0.184 & 0.346*** & 0.129 & 0.051 \\
 K & -0.006* & -0.007** & -0.007** & -0.009*** \\
 L & -0.014 & -0.022* & -0.021* & -0.023** \\
 M & -0.006 & -0.001 & -0.004 & -0.002 \\
 N & 0.001 & 0.004 & 0.009 & 0.003 \\
 O & 0.01 & 0.017 & -0.003 & 0.003 \\
 P & -0.077 & -0.146*** & -0.103** & -0.093** \\
 Q & -0.022*** & -0.002 & -0.004 & -0.007 \\
 R & 0.028*** & 0.035*** & 0.032*** & 0.027*** \\
 T & 0.0003 & -0.007 & 0.005 & -0.009 \\
 U & -0.149** & -0.052 & 0.055 & 0.077 \\
 V & -0.017* & -0.020** & -0.016* & -0.014* \\
 W & -0.006 & -0.005 & 0.002 & -0.0004 \\
 Z & -0.006 & -0.003 & -0.003 & -0.006 \\
 AB & 0.004*** & 0.005*** & 0.005*** & 0.004*** \\
 AC & -0.056** & -0.058** & -0.045* & -0.028 \\
 AD & 1.985** & 0.856 & 0.178 & 0.306 \\
 AE & & -0.028*** & -0.012* & -0.012 \\
 AF & & 0.043*** & 0.044*** & 0.042*** \\
 AG & & -0.043*** & -0.037*** & -0.036*** \\
 AH & & -0.007 & -0.004 & -0.008 \\
 AI & & -0.003 & -0.004 & -0.003 \\
 AJ & & -0.014 & -0.003 & 0.004 \\
 BA & & & -0.030*** & -0.031*** \\
 BC & & & -0.038*** & -0.039*** \\
 BD & & & -0.042*** & -0.044*** \\
 BE & & & -0.025*** & -0.028*** \\
 BF & & & -0.032*** & -0.036*** \\
 BH & & & -0.034*** & -0.058*** \\
 BJ & & & 0.006 & -0.013 \\
 BI & & & -0.027*** & -0.048*** \\
 BL & & & -0.028*** & -0.051*** \\
 BM & & & 0.030*** & 0.012 \\
 BL * FC & & & & -0.0005 \\
 BM * FC & & & & 0.009** \\
 BC * FC & & & & 0.013 \\
 BO * FC & & & & 0.052*** \\
 BP * FC & & & & -0.036** \\
 Constant & 0.131* & 0.039 & -0.032 & -0.03 \\
 \midrule
 Observations & 1,210 & 1,210 & 1,210 & 1,210 \\
 $R^2$ & 0.126 & 0.187 & 0.28 & 0.301 \\
 Adjusted $R^2$ & 0.106 & 0.164 & 0.254 & 0.272 \\
Residual\cr Std. Error & 0.003 & 0.003 & 0.002 & 0.002 \\
 $F$ Statistic & 6.325*** & 8.204*** & 10.552*** & 0.417*** \\
  \bottomrule
\addlinespace
 \multicolumn{5}{c}{* $ p<0.1 $; ** $ p<0.05 $; *** $ p<0.01 $} \\
\end{tabularx}%
\end{ThreePartTable}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: All `S` columns can have common `table-format` as defined in `\sisetup{...}` and also `table-space-text-post=***`. Two exception of numbers with four decimal digital can protrude in space reserved for stars. Considering this the table can begin with `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X@{}*{4}{S}}`. With this will table looks more nice (to my opinion, of course). +1 for nice answer.

Comment: @Zarko: For `table-format`, I first used a common value for the four `S` columns. That produced  3   `overfull  \hbox`, so I opted for two different values. Not sure this was the best choice, though.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you. The table format is completely disturbs when I place the actual names of variables in the table that are bit longer but I cannot post variable names here. However, I can make the column width adjusted to text.

Comment: Can't you write variable names over two lines? You also can play with fontsize inside the table, and with the value of `\tabcolsep`. But of course it all depends on the actual variable names.

Answer (score 1):

Use `\caption*` for the note:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[para]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs,longtable,tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\setlength{\LTcapwidth}{7in}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttablex}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{l*{4}{S}} 
  \caption{Ordinary Least Square Estimations}\label{tab:te3}\\
  \caption*{%
    Note: This table provides the results of OLS. Four models are estimated
    here. Models details are provided in the main body of the document.
  }\\
  \toprule
  {\bfseries{}}  &{\bfseries(1)} & {\bfseries(2)} &{\bfseries(3)} & {\bfseries(4)} \\%
  \endfirsthead
  \caption[]{-- continued from previous page}\\
  \toprule
  & {\bfseries(1)} & {\bfseries(2)} &{\bfseries(3)} & {\bfseries(4)}\\
  \midrule
  \endhead
  \bottomrule
  \addlinespace
  \multicolumn{5}{r}{\footnotesize Continued on next page} \\
  \endfoot
  \bottomrule
  \addlinespace
  \insertTableNotes\\
  \endlastfoot %
  \midrule
  A   & 0.022*** & 0.019*** & 0.021*** & 0.020*** \\
  B    & -0.002 & -0.008** & -0.010*** & -0.010** \\
  C  & 0.024 & -0.007 & -0.004 & -0.015 \\
  D    & -0.217*** & -0.314*** & -0.275*** & -0.262*** \\
  E   & -0.133 & -0.068 & -0.071 & -0.026 \\
  F   & 0.023 & 0.003 & 0.022 & 0.019 \\
  G    & -0.003*** & -0.003*** & -0.002** & -0.002** \\
  H    & -0.015 & -0.021** & -0.041*** & -0.045*** \\
  I   & -0.005** & -0.006*** & -0.006*** & -0.007*** \\
  J   & 0.184 & 0.346*** & 0.129 & 0.051 \\
  K & -0.006* & -0.007** & -0.007** & -0.009*** \\
  L & -0.014 & -0.022* & -0.021* & -0.023** \\
  M  & -0.006 & -0.001 & -0.004 & -0.002 \\
  N    & 0.001 & 0.004 & 0.009 & 0.003 \\
  O  & 0.01  & 0.017 & -0.003 & 0.003 \\
  P  & -0.077 & -0.146*** & -0.103** & -0.093** \\
  Q  & -0.022*** & -0.002 & -0.004 & -0.007 \\
  R   & 0.028*** & 0.035*** & 0.032*** & 0.027*** \\
  S    & 0.006 & 0.035*** & 0.026*** & 0.025*** \\
  T   & 0.0003 & -0.007 & 0.005 & -0.009 \\
  U   & -0.149** & -0.052 & 0.055 & 0.077 \\
  V   & -0.017* & -0.020** & -0.016* & -0.014* \\
  W     & -0.006 & -0.005 & 0.002 & -0.0004 \\
  Z    & -0.006 & -0.003 & -0.003 & -0.006 \\
  AB  & 0.004*** & 0.005*** & 0.005*** & 0.004*** \\
  AC  & -0.056** & -0.058** & -0.045* & -0.028 \\
  AD   & 1.985** & 0.856 & 0.178 & 0.306 \\
  AE    &       & -0.028*** & -0.012* & -0.012 \\
  AF   &       & 0.043*** & 0.044*** & 0.042*** \\
  AG    &       & -0.043*** & -0.037*** & -0.036*** \\
  AH   &       & -0.007 & -0.004 & -0.008 \\
  AI    &       & -0.003 & -0.004 & -0.003 \\
  AJ    &       & -0.014 & -0.003 & 0.004 \\
  BA  &       &       & -0.030*** & -0.031*** \\
  BC  &       &       & -0.038*** & -0.039*** \\
  BD  &       &       & -0.042*** & -0.044*** \\
  BE  &       &       & -0.025*** & -0.028*** \\
  BF  &       &       & -0.032*** & -0.036*** \\
  BH  &       &       & -0.034*** & -0.058*** \\
  BJ  &       &       & 0.006 & -0.013 \\
  BI  &       &       & -0.027*** & -0.048*** \\
  BL  &       &       & -0.028*** & -0.051*** \\
  BM  &       &       & 0.030*** & 0.012 \\
  BL * FC &       &       &       & -0.0005 \\
  BM * FC &       &       &       & 0.009** \\
  BC * FC &       &       &       & 0.013 \\
  BO * FC &       &       &       & 0.052*** \\
  BP * FC &       &       &       & -0.036** \\
  Constant & 0.131* & 0.039 & -0.032 & -0.03 \\
  \midrule
  Observations & 1,210 & 1,210 & 1,210 & 1,210 \\
  $R^2$    & 0.126 & 0.187 & 0.28  & 0.301 \\
  Adjusted $R^2$ & 0.106 & 0.164 & 0.254 & 0.272 \\
  Residual Std. Error & 0.003 & 0.003 & 0.002 & 0.002 \\
  $F$ Statistic & 6.325*** & 8.204*** & 10.552***  & 0.417*** \\
  \bottomrule
  \multicolumn{5}{c}{*p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01} \\
\end{longtable}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. But there is still one problem. Table note goes out of the margins of the table. However, I can keep it within the margins of the table.